# Bootstrap Tabs do not work with AngularJS/ Angular-Form-Builder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, typeerror

In my project I use Bootstrap Tabs with AngularJS and angular-form-builder:

```
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#project" aria-controls="projekt" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Projekt</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#project2" aria-controls="podglad" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Podgląd</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#json" aria-controls="json" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Json</a></li>
            </ul>

           <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="project">
           ...
           ...
```

Whenever I try to move between tabs I recieve an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function(anonymous function) @ VM4062:4b.event.dispatch @ angular-file-upload.js:1331b.event.add.v.handle @ angular-file-upload.js:1331triggerMouseEvent @ angular-file-upload.js:1331tapClick @ angular-file-upload.js:1331tapMouseUp @ angular-file-upload.js:1331
```

Of course I didn't forget about handling the tabs:

```
 $('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
})
```

I think its also worth mentioning that my application has 3 levels of nested views(via UI - Router)

Has anyone stumbled upon similar problem in the past?
All my libraries are properly loaded within the project (I do believe in correct order, other parts of the application work as expected to).

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap tabs won't work natively with AngularJS, and your JQuery obviously isn't working correctly either. It's generally bad practice to use JQuery to modify the DOM in an Angular project, you should try to do things *the Angular way*. This means using directives which properly inject/update the DOM.

Since you are using Bootstrap, you should look into using [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) in your project. It has the functionality you are looking for already. Alternatively, you could write your own directives which properly modify the tab `active` class.

Comment: But for some reason this combination(Angular + Bootstrap tabs) works just fine when used as stand-alone application. Its only when I place it as a part of whole project(as a template via ui-router) the error occurs.

Comment: Yes... that's because using JQuery to modify DOM elements in an Angular project doesn't work consistently, for various reasons. This is precisely why it is considered bad practice.

Comment: Oh, I see. Since I only have 3 tabs and they are extremely small I am considering using ng-show/hide.